# long-distance sound detection/recording solution?

Tags: amplifier, audio, detection

My general requirement is an audio input system which can effectively detect sound signal (80dB at about 5cm) over 30 meters away. The supply voltage should be within 5V so that the system can work with an embedded system such as a DSP microcontroller. I think the gain of the op-amp should be higher than 60 dB, AGC is preferred but not necessary.

Is there a solution or such an audio op-amp can meet my requirement?

Comment: This is about physics, not opamps. You would need a very directional microphone to pick that sound out from ambient noise. (Look into shotgun mics.) You cannot estimate amp gain until you know the mic sensitivity anyway. But you probably won't have much signal to play with.

Comment: Thank you, so do you think a directional mic can help to increase the detection distance? I was looking for some directional mics but they are not very sensitive ones...I did think about making a 2-mic array using directional mics just like human ears. As for the op-amp gain, I tested with a MAX9814 arduino module, I set its gain to the fixed 60 dB, placed a sound source about 25 meters away, the module could just pick up very weak signal. That's how I estimated the gain roughly

Comment: The solution used in sports audio is a parabolic reflected mic. The Friis-like path loss must be negated by selection of size and parabolic gain

Comment: Thank you, and I have looked into the parabolic reflected mic, but due to the size and some realistic limitations, plus it's a little beyond electrical engineering field. I switched to a sensitive electrical condenser mic.

Comment: it all  depends a great deal on what you are trying to do - what the sound source is and how clearly you need to pick it up. A shotgun will run you a lot less than a parabolic I think, and might be enough. Worry about the mic first, then get the preamp right. Try reading this. http://blog.shure.com/choosing-a-shotgun-microphone-the-long-and-short-of-it/

Comment: I am afraid shotgun mic is too big for my application

Comment: Then tell us about your application's specific needs. I remember we've been exactly at the same point on dsp.stackexchange.com.

Comment: The audio receiver should be able to detect and demodulate the audio signal from the transmitter, the audio signal is chirp signal. Then the receivers mic array use this received signal to do further cross-correlation process.

Comment: SNR depends on Noise spectrum and path loss of signal spectrum.  Now which part of this do you not understand? The ratio in dB determines what mic gain and amplifier signal filtering is needed from this input spec.

Answer (score 3):

If your sound is 80dB (I assume you mean at a level of 80dBSPL) at 5cm, it will be at a level of 25dBSPL at 30m.

You need to start with the sensitivity and noise level of microphones. Most document the sensitivity, some document their noise level. Unless the signal to noise ratio at the output of the microphone is good enough for detection, then no amount of 'good' op-ampery will make it better. A bad op-amp can make it worse however.

If the original sound signal has enough structure to allow DSP to do something useful, so if it's a narrowband tone, or a chirp, or something predictable, then you can reduce the effective noise bandwidth with DSP processing.

Your fundamental problem is the 25dBSPL level. This can be improved without additional noise by a directional microphone, either a parabolic or shotgun, or at some expense with a microphone array.

Comment: This is the time when you want to write down your link power budget. You know the transmitted power, the path loss, and you can shop around for a microphone - noise floor (NEP). You can improve things by increasing the gain of the transmitting and receiving  antennas (ie a directional horn on your source & detector) You'll also want to know the bandwidth of the signal you wish to detect. Might also want to think about interfering signals - and their spectral content.

Comment: When you talk about "noise" ,"Unless the signal to noise ratio at the output of the microphone is good enough for detection", do you mean the acoustic noise from the ambient environment or electronic noise generated by the circuit? I used to think that the acoustic stimulation should be at least higher than the electronic noise level to let the receiver detect it.

Comment: @ShuoLi Noise, both acoustic and electrical, is energy that cannot be detected as wanted signal, in the receiver processing bandwidth. For instance, the GPS signal arrives at ground level at a power level lower than thermal noise, and just one of half a dozen satellites in the same RF bandwidth, but because they're spread spectrum, receiver processing reduces the observation bandwidth by orders of magnitude. They have 'enough structure' to allow DSP to 'do something useful' to reduce the effective noise bandwidth. There are several ways to do this, so I've not included details.